# Android: Employing ImageButton with ListView

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton

I’ve delved into the Android documentation that is somewhat nebulous regarding my question.  Is it possible to overlay an ImageButton over a ListView employing a SimpleExpandableListAdapter?  If so, pointing me in the right direction (code example or technical specs) would be most appreciative.

Additional clarification:  I’m designing/developing a prototype courseware app template to be used in advanced degree programs.  For this specific piece, the upper 2/3 of the screen will contain  a ListView employing a SimpleExpandableListAdapter that pulls such items as lesson orientation, activities, and assessment instruments from a resource file (text file to make it easier to populate/modify).  The lower 1/3 will be comprised of ImageButtons that control the flow of other lesson functions such as RSS feeds, access to school Websites, and arrow buttons that will change the contents of the upper 2/3 of the screen while leaving the lower 1/3 screen as is.  In essence, a customized GUI menu system at the lower 1/3 of the screen.  Thus, looking to determine if it is technically feasible to layer ImageButtons over a ListView.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some more details about what exactly you are trying to accomplish??  You want an ImageButton floating on top of a ListView?  In that case, you can use a FrameLayout to have two layers of widgets..